# Java code Detect Special character in CSV file

Tags: java, arrays, regex, java-8, regex-group

Hi am looking for a java code that will detect special characters like below in a csv file.

```
þ–J¹ØÀ8”‹Ýøm~”o^ÒÀŸ¢Æ~]®QÅ6›j„VaºÊº’>Ô)2¡@,K1¨!ïZS¯W›÷�
```

This what I tried so far but its not working

```
package routines;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class DefectCharacter {

public static boolean Character_Validation(String password) 
{
    if(password.length()>0)
    {
        Pattern special = Pattern.compile ("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");

           Matcher hasSpecial = special.matcher(password);
           
           return hasSpecial.find();

    }
    else
        return false;

    }
}
```

If those special characters or unreadable string is found it should display me a message. Any advice or help how I can achieve this?

Comment: You surely mean something more like `boolean hasSpecial = !password.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");` since there are many characters that are 'special'. Too many to pattern match

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** You should be aware that your string of special characters also contains regular characters like `J`, `6`, `Q`, `8`, `1`, `K`, `Z`, `S`, `W`, `V`, `o`, `2` and `a`, you may want to clean your special character string.

Just search for the special characters and output a message if one is found, for example:

```
package routines;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public static boolean Character_Validation(String password) {
    if(password.length() > 0) {

        Pattern special = Pattern.compile("[þ–J¹ØÀ8”‹Ýøm~”o^ÒÀŸ¢Æ~\\]®QÅ6›j„VaºÊº’>Ô\\)2¡@,K1¨!ïZS¯W›÷�]");

        Matcher hasSpecial = special.matcher(password);
        
        boolean found = hasSpecial.find();
        
        if(found) {
            System.out.println("Special character found.");
        }
        
        return found;
    }

    return false;
}
```